# Why does this regex not match the URLs in this Google results page?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm having trouble scraping the URLs out of the Google results. This code worked for me for a long time but seems like Google changed a few things this week and now I'm getting a ton of extra characters surrounded by the actual URL I want.

```
preg_match_all('@<h3\s*class="r">\s*<a[^<>]*href="([^<>]*)"[^<>]*>(.*)</a>\s*</h3>@siU',     $results, $matches[$key]);
```

**EDIT**

All links come out like this when scraped with the above code

```
/url?url=http://cooksandtravelbooks.com/write-for-us/&rct=j&sa=U&ei=XdayUNnHBIqDiwKZuYEY&ved=0CBQQFjAA&q=cooking+%5C%22Write+for+Us%5C%22&usg=AFQjCNGMiCiWYY_8JDAhqJggVDW2qHRMfw
```

Comment: I suggest not using regex to parse html... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. You'd better use something like phpquery or any other DOM parser than regex.

Comment: It works for me.  Can you show us an example or two of the incorrect results, and the code you use to retrieve them?  (And not in a comment, please.  Edit the question and add this info to it.)

Comment: You're not getting the "actual URLs" because when you click on a Google link you're actually going back to Google and then they redirect you to the real URL.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($data);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href');
    echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  I've added it to http://htmlparsing.com/php.html, which I post in response to most of these PHP HTML parsing questions.

Comment: Might want to also note that the @suppress character is necessary to hide any errors due to invalid html markup.

Comment: Note added.  Thanks.  The source for the site is on GitHub if anyone wants to contribute: https://github.com/petdance/htmlparsing/

Comment: Unfortunately im still not having any better luck getting the actual URL's with this method so far.